# Compile to JAR in Eclipse (while GiT repo present)

Tags: java, eclipse, git, jar

I've searched and I found some things about compiling to JARs in Eclipse, but nothing that seems to mention my issue.

I decided I would like to version my source code using GiT, so in my project workspace (in the src directory) I initialized a GiT repo. Now, the GiT repo creates a hidden folder called "/.git" that lives within the repo folder (again, in my case, "src"). Now, when I try to export to a JAR, it seemingly just takes all resources from the "src" directory (as well as all other files from the project's workspace), and errors out on compilation.

I could easily cut the files, compile to JAR, and then paste them back there afterwards, but I would like something less hackish and more smooth.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for all your replies,

-M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, make a git repository outside the `src` folder

**or**

use Maven and tell the jar plugin (used for packing `.class` files and other resources into a `.jar`) to exclude the `.git` folder. Link to the [exclude option](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#excludes).

Comment: Thanks for the answer alegen, but I think it may even be simpler still. I was moving too fast and didn't realize that I could select (or deselect) subfolders of the project to include. Oops :)